# Turning jQuery event listener on after off

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events

So I want to turn off a jQuery event under a certain condition (if the user scrolls down) but if they do the opposite (scroll up) then I want the event turned to on so that it will fire.

This is my code but as I am new to jQuery, I am pretty sure I'm missing something in the handler - I just don't know what it should be.

Here is the code:

```
 function myFunction() {


var handler = function(e){
    //code here
}
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) {
         // scrolling downwards
         $(window).off("scroll", handler);  
         } 

       if(scroll < position) {
         //scrolling upwards
         $(window).on("scroll", handler); 
         hypeDocument.showPreviousScene(hypeDocument.kSceneTransitionPushTopToBottom, 1.1)
         }
    position = scroll;
});



}
```

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I'm new to jQuery

Comment: @Tushar I am using the .on and .off method in the `$(window).on("scroll", handler);`

Comment: i feel you are trying to do something the wrong hard long way

Comment: @MuhammadUmer ok is there any other way you could do it? I don't know much jQuery but basically want to disable the event temporarily.

Comment: make variable that is outside, like  `var disabled=false;` then then inside handler put `if (disabled) return;` and when you want to disable just do `disabled=true`, and when go back to not being disable `disabled=false;`

Comment: also if i understand correctly you want to fire handler ONLY when someone scrolls up correct

Answer (score 1):

try using an if-else statement instead of two ifs

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function()
{

var handler = function(e){
    // hypeDocument.showPreviousScene(hypeDocument.kSceneTransitionPushTopToBottom, 1.1)
    console.log('handler');
}

var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > position) {
         // scrolling downwards
         // NOTHING
         } 

       if(scroll < position) {
         //scrolling upwards
         handler();
         }
    position = scroll;
});

});
```

Open console and you'll see "handler" in output each time you scroll up.

1. You need to add scroll handler after `document.ready` event:

   ```
    $(function() {
         /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    });
   ```
2. I think you doing wrong trying to subscribe and unsubscribe your handler.
   You should just determine the direction of scroll as you do.
   Then if it is right direction – call your handler:

   ```
   if (scroll < position) {
        //scrolling upwards
        handler();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for that, however I am running the javascript in one function and am then stopping it from another function. I have to do this due to a software limitation. Is there any way that it could be done with this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your comment is not very clear for me.
Please provide more information about the process and functions.

Comment: Basically, I have two 'scenes' which are similar to pages in the software I am using. I run the javascript on one scene and it continues to run for the entire project, but basically I want to stop the scroll from happening on a single scene so was using `$(window).on("scroll");` to stop the scroll down but it also prevents the scroll up from working. See these screenshots: http://1drv.ms/1M4vlIj

Comment: I think you cannot do what do you want in that particular way.
Please provide a details for your scenario.

Am I right?
When you at the `scene1` you could scroll anywhere.
When you get to the `scene2` you need be able to scroll up but to not scroll down?

Comment: You need more information from `hypeDocument` to deal with that. It's hard to provide concrete code sample without real code.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 3:** in future you could do this instead.

```
var nT = $(window).scrollTop,  pos = nT(), func = function(e){ /*code here*/ };

$(window).scroll(()=>(nT()<pos)&&(pos=nT(),func())); //make people hate you.
```

**Update 2:** and to make it even smaller..

```
var newTop = $(window).scrollTop,  position = newTop(),
handler = function(e){ /*code here*/ };

$(window).scroll(function() {
    (newTop()<position)&&(position=newTop(),handler());
});
```

**Update:** Or you could make it even better

```
var newTop = $(window).scrollTop,  position = newTop();

var handler = function(e){
    //code here
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = newTop();
    if(scroll < position) handler();
    position = scroll;
});
```

Use Boolean variable instead of attaching/detaching event.

```
var disabled= false,
    newTop = $(window).scrollTop,
    position = newTop();

var handler = function(e){
    if (disabled) return;
    //code here
};


$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = newTop();
    if(scroll > position) disabled=true;
    else disabled=false; 
    position = scroll;
});
```

Comment: thanks for that. will give it a shot and let you know how it goes :) How exactly would I set the variable to be true?

Comment: when you want event to not fire, disabled= true

Comment: I am having real difficulty with this. As I said, I am a beginner so if I could explain a bit more clearly could you help? Basically when the user tries to scroll down, it should just do nothing. Thinking of using 'off' to stop the scrolling method. Then if they scroll up, they can do so and the event will occur normally.